# Please revise the latest blog to state it's only about C++ security issues

Tags: discussion, blog

We've had a [recent blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2019/12/02/preventing-the-top-security-weaknesses-found-in-stack-overflow-code-snippets/?cb=1) that enumerates common security issues found on Stack Overflow and their solutions.

To do that, it refers back to [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.01321), which describes vulnerabilities in C++ code found on Stack Overflow. However, on the blog, it's nowhere to be found that it's only about C++ vulnerabilities.

Other tags, such as the PHP, JavaScript, C# and VB.NET tags, in the meantime, are riddled with different vulnerabilities, mainly [CWE-89](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/89.html) (SQL injection) and [CWE-79](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/79.html) (XSS).

I'm personally willing to bet that more questions/answers on Stack Overflow have code vulnerable to SQL injection than all of the vulnerabilities listed in the blog combined.

Misrepresenting threats, even in a blog, leads to bad security practice. Either the blog should address actual dangers when copying code from Stack Overflow, or it should clearly specify (my preference would be in the title) that it only addresses C++ vulnerabilities (note that the article referenced to *does* specify this in the title).

Comment: For a broad and uneducated audience on the topic the blog is wonderful click-bait and a great conversation starter at the coffee-machine. In that sense it serves its goal. Nothing on the blog needs to be factual correct. it is riddled with contributions that are artistic interpretations of topics marginally related to the site or its community.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thanks for the feedback. I've updated the article to indicate that these CWEs were the most common in the research on C++ code. However, I'm not going to change the title, as these CWEs can affect multiple languages.

Comment: The fact that coding errors can occur in multiple languages is an irrefutable fact, but does little to justify a fundamentally wrong title. The Stack Overflow Blog has never been a place that one goes to find facts or credible evidence, and now we see why. Even when called out and given a chance to fix a potentially inadvertent misleading error, the chance is not taken. I won't speculate as to the reasons, but they aren't flattering.